# how to find uninitialized stack variable

Tags: c++, c, stack, intel, icc

I have received a legacy code(c) which seemed to produce different results at different times.
I was able to reproduce this problem consistently using intel's compiler and compiler flag -ftrapuv, this worked wonderfully and I was able to determine that the uninitialized variable was some stack variable.
The question is, what is the next phase? 
Does anyone know how to print a back trace of all stack variables? (or simply print the stack content)
Does anyone have a suggestion or knows how intel might be able to help? or I should proceed with this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try valgrind, it finds reads of uninitialized variables and prints the stacktrace.

Comment: You can use the new & improved UBSanitizer from the upcoming CLang and GCC versions!

Comment: Turn on all warnings when you compile. Or use any of a number of static analyzers. (I won't mention the one I used to work for, but it is very expensive and the best. Find a cheaper free one: this error is not hard for the tools to find.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `-ftrapuv` or Valgrind's [memcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) as suggested in the comments can work, but these are dynamic analysis that will only catch errors exercised at runtime; if your test execution does not exercise the buggy code, these tools won't be helpful.

Fortunately, use of uninitialized stack variables can often be easily detected statically, and your compiler has flags that can help you catch this. Both gcc and Intel's icc support the `-Wuninitialized` flag that will print warnings about the offending code. gcc also supports a `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` flag that will warn when there are *some* code paths on which the variable may be used uninitialized; do note that this latter analysis is prone to false positives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sparse` which is use to do static analysis of code. It is open source and very powerful tool. links here:

- http://kernelnewbies.org/Sparse
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sparse.1.html